# Find max number in an array using function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I need to use function that takes an array of numbers as an argument. The function is to return the largest value from the set (variable randomNumbers). I need to assign the result of the action to a variable (result). Here below is my code which is not working and I don't know where to use the variable result.

```
const randomNumbers = [27, 64, 47, 78, 48, 11, 76, 25, 11, 83];
function maxFromArray(numbers) {
    let max = numbers;
    for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i > max) {
            max = numbers[i];
        }
        }return(max);
}
    console.log(maxFromArray(randomNumbers));
```

Comment: max = numbers[0]

Comment: `Math.max(...randomNumbers);`

Answer (score 0):

You need as start value for `max` the value at index zero. Inside of the condition, you need the actual value.

The [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) needs only an expression without wrapping in parentheses.

```js
function maxFromArray(numbers) {
    let max = numbers[0];                      // first item
    for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > max) {                // take item at index
            max = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return max;                                // return without parentheses
}

const randomNumbers = [27, 64, 47, 78, 48, 11, 76, 25, 11, 83];
console.log(maxFromArray(randomNumbers));
```